# edittext.gettext().tostring().isempty() condition executing even when there is text in the EditText?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

I'm trying to do something like this: I'm trying to check if there is text is the `EditText` using `gettext().tostring().isempty()`. If there is no text, a `Snackbar` will be shown and if there is some text, another method will get executed.

Here's the code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a unique username");
            builder.setView(R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (uniqueUserName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Please choose a unique username", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        signingUpMethod();
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Yes, as guessed by @android_dev, `uniqueUserName` is in `R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog` and I'm inflating it in `onCreate()` like this:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog, null);
    uniqueUserName = (EditText) alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.uniqueUserName);
```

The problem is that either times (when edittext is empty and filled) the snackbar is getting shown. I don't know why is this happening!!

Please let me know.

Comment: Well obviously your isEmpty statement is returning true somehow. Why not try checking if length == 0 instead?

Comment: @JakeMiller what do you mean by 'the method which populates `uniqueUserName` (input)'. There isn't any such method, I think. The EditText is filled by the user.

Comment: @Dportology Nopes, it didn't worked!

Comment: Does your textview have a "android:text=" property set in the xml?

Comment: ´not sure but cant u access the EditText directly because if u do convert stuff to strings sometime if theyre null itll create a string "null" or ""

Comment: Instead of using `.isEmpty()` , try using `TextUtils.isEmpty(uniqueUserName.getText().toString())`

Comment: also can u please run ur code and add
`Log.wtf("tag",uniqueUserName.getText().toString());`
after
`if (uniqueUserName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {`
so we know WHAT the editText is

Comment: So, you mean to say that even after entering text in EditText the condition of checking isEmpty() always turns out to be true. And you also tried with length with no luck. Hmm... where exactly are you inflating uniqueUserName, I guess it has to be part of choose_unique_name_dialog layout.

Comment: @android_dev you guessed it right, buddy. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @HammadNasir Not sure but have you tried setting builder.setView(alertDialogView) rather than builder.setView(R.layout.choose_unique_name_dialog)

Comment: @Dportology please see the edited question

Comment: you are inflating it, but that's not what you are using when creating the alertview. those views are different instances.

Comment: Try using edittext().getText().trim().equals("");

Comment: @android_dev 's answer worked for me :)